# How to store all ACL permissions in a table?

Tags: cakephp, acl

I'm using CakePHP to make an application. I want to see an overview of all permissions by aro's and aco's.

What is the best way to store all these permissions in a table?
(Without using a plugin)

Comment: Do you really need acl? It is usually overhead in 90% of all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [reading the chapter in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html) about ACL?

All information you need is there.